# Why is nohup not bound with &?

Tags: nohup

When I use `nohup` I see it automatically "ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out". `&` is used to tell OS to run the program in background. Then why doesn't `nohup` imply `&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the shell does not know or care what `nohup` is.  It just knows you said to run X, and wait for it to finish, so that is what it does.

Comment: So `&` is for shell and `nohup` is not?

Comment: @MichaelMa, yes; `nohup` is a program, and the & is a signal to the shell.